# Filter django queryset including a specific object in manytomany field

Tags: django, filter, many-to-many

Here is my models,

```
class Age(models.Model):
    layer = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    ...
class Course(models.Model):
    target_age = models.ManyToManyField('Age')
    ...
```

How can I get a course queryset including a specific age?
views:

```
request_courses = Course.objects.filter(target_age ...
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your question is a little vague. First, have a read of the documentation on [querying across relationships.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

If you want to get courses related to only those `Age`'s with a particular field value:

```
Course.objects.filter(target_age__FIELD=...)
```

where FIELD is the field in your `Age` model you want to query against.

Alternatively, if you have an `Age` object and you want to get all courses that are actually related to a particular `Age` object, you need:

```
age = Age.objects.get(...)
courses = Course.objects.filter(target_age=age)
```

or if you want to get courses that are related to at least one of a number of possible `Age`'s:

```
ages = Age.objects.filter(...)
courses = Course.objects.filter(target_age__id__in=ages.values_list('id'))
```

**EDIT**

The last example is using [the `in` lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in)

Comment: Sorry for my less information. The case I'm asking for is exactly the last one! And, can't I get a query using the second one if course has multiple target_age, right?